# ¿Cómo hacer un request post?

Tags: python, python-requests

estoy interesado en saber como puedo enviar datos en un formulario HTML.
La página es la siguiente:
https://help.instagram.com/contact/723586364339719/
Es simplemente para hacer un programa para reportar, quiero hacerlo para ponerme a prueba a mí mismo.
Hice este código pero no se si funciona.

```
import requests
from time import sleep


url = 'https://help.instagram.com/ajax/help/contact/submit/page'

datos = {
    'Field258021274378282':'Usuario',
    'Field735407019826414':'Nombre del usuario',
    'Field506888789421014[year]':'2012',
    'Field506888789421014[month]':'4',
    'Field506888789421014[day]':'14',
    'Field294540267362199':'Non-Family'
}

while True:
    r = requests.post(url, data=datos)
    print("Hola")
    sleep(30)
```

Comment: En vez de imprimir "Hola" puedes imprimir el contenido que el servidor te remite (`r.text`) o el [código de estado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP) de la respuesta (`r.status_code`)  para saber si laa petición es correcta, si ha sido aceptada o no, fallo del servidor, etc

Comment: @FJSevilla si, perdón. Lo de hola es simplemente para comprobar cada vez que el bucle realiza sus acciones. La respuesta del status code es 400. Y text no lo puedo poner por aquí.